# How to set multiple audience in urban airship

Tags: php, android, ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am using php client to send notification request to urban airship. 
For that I have referred below link. 
https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/70144047-Simple-PHP-API-v3-examples 
In that audience is set to

```
$push = array("audience"=>"all", "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>$platform);
```

I want to sent notification so selected iOS and Android devices. 
For that I am creating an array for iOS and android each. 
like this.

```
$iosDevices = array(); 
array_push($iosDevices, "Channel_id_for_iOS_device_1"); 
array_push($iosDevices, "Channel_id_for_iOS_device_2"); 
$main__channel['ios_channel'] = $iosDevices;
$push = array("audience"=>  $main__channel,"notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>$platform);
```

This works fine, however when I try to add channel id array of android it doesn't allow me.

```
$androidDevices = array(); 
array_push($androidDevices, "Channel_id_for_android_device_1"); 
array_push($androidDevices, "Channel_id_for_android_device_2"); 
$main_channel['android_channel'] = $androidDevices; 
$push = array("audience"=> $main__channel,"notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>$platform);
```

I want to send notification to both iOS and android devices ids(selected one only). 
And I want to pass those array to audience. Is there any way to do so?

**Response**

> {"ok":false,"error":"Could not parse request
>   body.","error_code":40210,"details":{"error":"Specified more than one
>   type of selector ('android_channel' was
>   unexpected)","path":"audience.android_channel[0]","location":{"line":1,"column":127}},"operation_id":"2b00a2a0-73cd-11e5-a4ba-90e2ba2901f0"}
>   Got negative response from server: 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the reply from urban airship support. below is the answer.

```
"audience": {
      "OR": [
         { "ios_channel": [ 
            "Channel_id_for_iOS_device_1", 
            "Channel_id_for_iOS_device_1" 
         ] },
         { "android_channel": [ 
            "Channel_id_for_android_device_1", 
            "Channel_id_for_android_device_2", 
            "Channel_id_for_android_device_3" 
         ] }
      ]
   }
```

I tested it, It works fine for both iOS and android.